# Sitecore database deployment

Tags: sql-server, deployment, sitecore

### The Issue

I want to get sitecore items, from database environment one to environment two without manually having to recreate the databases.

I cannot back and restore because the databases are constantly out of sync.

I cannot publish items from environment 1 to environment 2 because of company policy and restrictions on publishing items from dev to live.

### The Environment

I have essentially two database environments.

- Development
- Live

Each has three databases.

- Web
- Core
- Master

### The Wanted

I need to create a way of getting items from within development db to live db, at the moment I am stuck to a manual process and it's painful.

Any ideas, suggestion and solutions would be welcome. If there is a Sitecore solution then great, if there is a way to get difference in db's then that's cool. I need to pushed in the correct direction.

Comment: Is your "manual process" using the Sitecore Package Designer?

Comment: The manual process is manually creating new sitecore templates, layouts, sub-layouts, renderings and content items. Essentially replicating whats there in dev onto live db's. I cannot access live database via publishing target because of firewall restrictions blocking the development cms.

Comment: This is the first I have heard of package designer, is it what I want?

Comment: WOW! I didn't think you were meaning that manual. That is a lot of work. Yes. The packager, as Mark just answered, is a solution for you.

Comment: haha yes I feel like a write numpty. This looks perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to [learn how to use the Sitecore Packager](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Archive/SC53%20End%20User/Package%20Designer/The%20Package%20Designer%20Ribbon.aspx) to package up content into a zip file that you can deploy and install on a separate Sitecore instance.

Comment: Thank a chu again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Team Development for Sitecore (TDS)", see hhogdev.com. Or you could serialize the template and layout folder in dev, copy to live and deserialize there. It's out of the box functionality.

Comment: I would like to use hhogdev, lovely piece of software but seems business will not prioritize it to be brought within next year atleast sigh :(